# select all members using mysql join

Tags: mysql

I want to select all member who created something yesterday

**TABLE users**

```
userid   firstname    lastname
1         JOHN         DEO
2         JANE         DEO
```

**TABLE msg**

```
msg_id  msg_from   msg_to     received  age  city  country   timestamp
1       userid(1)  userid(2)  null      26   any   any       2018-10-04 14:37:12
```

**Query**

```
 SELECT
  SND.userid,
  SND.firstname,
  SND.lastname,
  M.age,
  M.city,
  M.country
FROM
  msg as M
  LEFT JOIN users as SND ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
WHERE
  M.timestamp >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

I want to select all members who created something yesterday

Comment: Welcome ! Please explain your problem . What is the meaning of something in 1 day?

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: i want to select members who created something like yesterday

Comment: Read: [Why is Select * considered harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SND.userid, 
       SND.firstname, 
       SND.lastname, 
       M.age, 
       M.city, 
       M.country
   FROM msg as M
     LEFT JOIN users as SND ON SND.userid = M.msg_from
   WHERE M.timestamp >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY );
```

You need to be consistent with the table aliases.

Ps.: I did not check the WHERE clause of you'r query.

Comment: thanks @Szekelygobe. thou it has still failed to work

Comment: You have a syntax error at the end of the SQL query. Of course, the OP should also be able to find that error, but they have been persistent in not following error messages.

Comment: the syntax error should be not putting "before select  to be "query" like that and remove ). there nothing else. and here i score like Query Score
65%

Comment: @Corion you can see the edit i made which is clear but still not getting results from db. so that means this doesn;t solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

finally got it fixed. i had problem with the whole query and table